# jQuery function with ELSE condition

Tags: jquery

Here is a simple question for a jQuery guru.

A work fiddle you can find [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/nVx7a/17/)

As you can see there is a container with `id="hideme"`. I want when I click on `link2` this `id` to hide, but with condition that when I click on `link1` or `link3` it must become visible again.

So I thought it must be  `} ELSE {` or it is not possible in jQuery?

```
$('#link2').click(function(){
    if(jQuery('#link2').data('clicked')) {
        $('#hideme').hide();
    } else {
        $('#hideme').show();
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `click` listener is only attached to `#link2`. You want to detect when any of the links are clicked, then do your test. Like so:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    if(this.id === 'link2') {
        $('#hideme').hide();
    } else {
        $('#hideme').show();
    };
});
```

Comment: Looks great! and it is close to waht i am looking for

Comment: Great! Glad to help @AndrewS! Would you mind accepting this as the answer since it helped you out? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Cannot be done by binding an event to '#link2', but can be done in two different other ways :

```
$('#link2').click(function(){
    $('#hideme').hide();
});

$('#link1, #link3').click(function(){
    $('#hideme').show();
});
```

or

```
$('ul a').click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('id') == 'link2') {
        $('#hideme').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('#hideme').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Not really, since you bind event to #link2 which cannot detect if #link1 or #link3 has been clicked .. since it's binded to #link2 :) .. but check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the separate events:

```
$('#link2').click(function() {
    $('#hideme').hide();
});

$('#link1, #link3').click(function() {
    $('#hideme').show();
});
```

I would actually make link1 and link3 have a common class to make selection "simpler".

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind `click` event to all links and apply condition in `handler`.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nVx7a/19/)**

```
$('[id^=link]').click(function () {    
    if (this.id == 'link2') $('#hideme').hide();
    else if (this.id == 'link1' || this.id == 'link2') $('#hideme').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use else statements this way as jQuery is very tunnel-visioned in it's event-binding.  Bind some event to some element and that will happen.  If you want another event to happen in another case, simply define it as such.  That being said you CAN use javascript statements in jQuery like so:

```
if(x = 0)
{
    $("div").hide();
} 
else
{
    $("div").show();
}
```

But in this instance you are using a logical operator against some external variable.  When binding an event this is entirely unnecessary.  Try taking a look at the toggle() feature.  Here's a simple example:

```
$("#id").click(function() {
    $("#MyDiv").toggle();
});
```